# Как сообщать команде, что пора выполнить CanExecute? с# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Недавно начал изучать MVVM и пока от него больше проблем. А то что называют слабой связанностью - для меня скорее "Слабо отслеживаемое поведение". 
Использую Prism.wpf. Создал DelegateCommand. В CanExecute указал bool переменную модели.
При каждом изменение переменной вызываю RaisePropertyChanged(). Но кнопка на которой висит команда не реагирует на изменения.
Что еще следует указывать, что бы СanExecute вызывался при каждом изменение переменой модели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DelegateCommand` в качестве `CanExecute` принимает *функцию*, которая проверяет некоторое условие и возвращает `bool`-значение, показывающее, может ли команда выполниться в данный момент. Вот простой пример:

```
string text;
public string Text
{
    get => text;
    set
    {
        if (Set(ref text, value))
            OK.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}

public DelegateCommand OK { get; }

public MainVm()
{
    OK = new DelegateCommand(_ => MessageBox.Show(Text),
                             _ => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text));
}
```

<sub>я не использую Prism, поэтому мои реализации могут отличаться, но принцип вы должны понять</sub>

Т.е. при каждом изменении `Text` мы говорим команде проверить возможность запуска, команда вызывает метод, который у нее есть: `_ => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text)` и получает от него результат.

В итоге:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button Content="OK" Command="{Binding OK}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вы по сути в ручную после каждого изменения текста вызываете CanExecute (  RaiseCanExecuteChanged() ). 
В wpf есть глобальная команда на обновление все команд. Я пробовал вызывать ее при изменении моей булевой переменной и ничего.

Comment: Вроде все как в вашем примере. Но у меня wpf отказывается обновлять кнопку. При этом под отладкой видно, что CanExecute - отдаст True. Он просто не вызывается.

Comment: Мой код у вас заработал?

Comment: Можно, конечно, использовать CommandManager.RequerySuggested, но мне это не нравится и я им не пользуюсь

Comment: Не проверял. Но вижу что должно работать. Создам новый проект. Поиграюсь с вашим кодом. Может пойму что к чему.

Comment: @NOP Работает. Почему то я считал, что WPF как-то сам догадается, что нужно выполнить CanExecute. Но видимо надо вызывать для каждого, влияющего на команду, свойства и события.